# jQuery remove check several ID's for one class name

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links, which when clicked get a class of "selected".

```
$("#" + filename).addClass("selected");
```

I have another button, which when clicked runs a different function. It also needs to remove all classes of `selected` from these links.

However there is no way to tell from the click of the button which link has the `selected` class so instead I need to check all of them for the class and remove it if it is present.

I expect the best way to do this would be to loop through all the link ID's and remove the `selected` class (so as not to repeat the code over and over).

So I guess, how could I combine the following into one loop?

I've prepared an array of all the link ID's called `var linkIDs`

```
var linkIDs = ["newpost", "getlink", "addpic","tags"];

$("#newpost").removeClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element has a class of "selected", you'll be able to select it with a class selector. You can simply:

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: Perfect! Much simpler than what I was thinking.